# Implementing @keypress in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, onkeypress

I am trying to implement `onkeypress` event in a Vue component. On keypress I want to restrict all key codes except numbers. I am trying the following.

Using the onkeypress event, things work fine!

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode === 0 || /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode)));" />
```

When I convert the above to be used in Vue, it does not work!!! :(

```
<input type="number" @keypress="restrictChars($event)" />

<script>
    export default {
    name: 'quantity-selector',
    methods: {
        restrictChars: function($event) {
            return ($event.charCode === 0 || /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode($event.charCode)));
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?? I don't understand what is going wrong? Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: you could use `v-model.number="yourmodel" @input="restrictChars"`

Comment: I am using v-model.number, but I don't see any documentation on @input. Would you be kind enough to send me a link?

Comment: Also this @input thing does not seem to be working across browsers. Works on chrome, not on Safari and Firefox.

Comment: i think the problem is in your method logic not in the events

Comment: What do you think the problem is? The method is supposed to return a boolean based on the pressed key. Which means true for all numbers and false for everything else.

Comment: i'm trying out your code and it works fine

Comment: Works fine on all browsers?? Tried Firefox and/or Safari. Works fine only in Chrome for me! I can still type alphabets in a number field on Firefox and Safari.

Comment: I figured out the problem! I should have been using `$event.preventDefault()` See answer!

Comment: i prefer to do `@keypress.prevent`

Comment: Any benefits of using `@keypress.prevent` over what I am proposing in the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the problem. Though I was returning a boolean when reading the keyCodes, I wasn't preventing the default keypress action. The `restrictChars` method should look something like this!

```
restrictChars: function($event) {
    if ($event.charCode === 0 || /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode($event.charCode))) {
        return true
    } else {
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: and does this fix the problem with others browsers?

Comment: yes absolutely! 100%. Chrome, Safari, Firefox (all latest versions) it works! I haven't tested on IE11 and Edge yet!

Comment: FYI, `charCode` is deprecated. You should be using `key` instead, and may have to change your logic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode